# Error with Geocode API in Ionic 2

Tags: google-maps, typescript, ionic2, geocode

I’m using the Google Maps Geocode API to read an address and place a marker on the map. This is how I’m using it :

```
for(let marker of markers){
this.geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
this.geocoder.geocode({
 'address': marker["address"]
}, (results,status) => {  
          var position = new google.maps.LatLng(results[0].geometry.location.lat(),results[0].geometry.location.lng()); // error pointing to this line
          this.personMarker = new google.maps.Marker({position: position, title: marker.name, markerInfo: marker, map : this.map , icon : marker.imageurl});
          google.maps.event.addListener(this.personMarker, 'click',  () => {
          this.showCard = true;
          this.org = marker.organization;
          this.gig = marker.gig;
          this.location = marker["address"];
          this.image = marker.imageurl;
          this.ngoData = marker;
          this.ownerusername = marker.ownerusername;
            });
     });
 }
```

I get this `error: ‘Cannot read property ‘0’ of null’` pointing to the line I’ve shown with a comment in the code snippet.Just don’t know what’s causing that error because I’m accessing the ‘results’ parameter only inside the `callback`. `console.log(results)` sometimes returns 'null' for the first iteration of the loop, followed by proper results for the rest of the iterations, or proper results for all iterations. I don't understand this inconsistent behavior, but I do know that I get this error usually when the intervals between me clicking and loading the map again is short.

I know that all the addresses are valid because sometimes all my markers appear on the map and the error doesn't turn up

Comment: Try it again and see if inspecting `status` will get you get an error code like `OVER_QUERY_LIMIT ` then post it here. Usually there's a Quota Per Second for the Geocode API and the other APIs. That might explain the intermittent behavior. I also suggest to always add a simple checker like `if (status === 'OK' && results)` before proceeding with using `results`.